# Show attributes on Shop Page of Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am trying to get two attributes to display on the shop page of my site (location and date). I found the following code and thought it would just be a case of changing $taxonomy = 'pa_country'; to $taxonomy = 'pa_location'; to make it display the attribute I wanted but it does not work. The labels display but the content is blank. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_size_attribute', 5 );
function display_size_attribute() {
global $product;
if ( $product->is_type('simple') ) {
    $taxonomy = 'pa_country';
    echo '<span class="attribute-s">Country: ' . $product->get_attribute($taxonomy) . '</span>','<br>';
}
 if ( $product->is_type('simple') ) {
    $taxonomy = 'pa_class';
    echo '<span class="attribute-s">Class: ' . $product->get_attribute($taxonomy) . '</span>','<br>';
}
 if ( $product->is_type('simple') ) {
    $taxonomy = 'pa_faction';
    echo '<span class="attribute-s">Faction: ' . $product->get_attribute($taxonomy) . '</span>','<br>';
}
 if ( $product->is_type('simple') ) {
    $taxonomy = 'pa_gender';
    echo '<span class="attribute-s">Gender: ' . $product->get_attribute($taxonomy) . '</span>','<br>';
}}
```